# Cypress test results do not appear in reportportal

Tags: testing, report, cypress, e2e-testing, reportportal

I'm using "cypress": "^8.7.0" and "@reportportal/agent-js-cypress": "^5.0.2" with node 14

My reportportal implementation is already running well with testcafe for another project. Now I tried setting it up with this project that uses cypress and the results just don't show up in RP. I followed every step shown here:
https://github.com/reportportal/agent-js-cypress

I turned on the debug option in the reporter options and I'm getting this output:

```
Finish test item ...
Success finish item ...
Finish test item ...
Success finish item ...
Finish launch ...
Success finish launch ...
```

This sounds like the launch worked but I do not see anything in RP. Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Is it possible that the other project can't access ReportPortal instance? We had a similar problem where our CI couldn't access ReportPortal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **/api/v1** at the end of your endpoint.

For example:

```
endpoint=https://reportportal.com/api/v1
```

I was facing the same issue with similar debug logs. Adding `/api/v1` in the endpoint solved the problem for me.

**Note** - `agent-js-cypress` is not yet supported with `Cypress 10.0` or above. Details https://github.com/reportportal/agent-js-cypress/issues/116